# Is there a validator for Bootstrap HTML?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Not "is there a Javascript form validator which works with Bootstrap" but "is there a validator which looks at your code and notes problems conforming to Bootstrap itself" — for instance

- column counts adding up to more than 12, which would be an Error
- rows outside a container, which would be a Warning, because you may have done it on purpose but it's somewhat unusual

I think this would be a good idea, especially as I'm getting into some very complex nested Bootstrap layouts.

Comment: No, there is no validator for Bootstrap HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you are asking for but.

Bootlint: https://github.com/twbs/bootlint